# Sealing existing vinyl tile

Tags: bathroom, vinyl-flooring

One small bathroom in a 1920s house. A cheap remodel was done what looks like about 20 years ago. We moved in recently and noticed water dripping through the ceiling below the bathroom after using the bath/shower. There appears to be a damaged gasket at the bath drain which I will replace. However, it seems that any water getting onto the bathroom floor is finding its way through and into the ceiling below, even small amounts when exiting/entering the shower.

I'm up to my eyeballs in other projects right now, and although I do plan on gutting this bathroom and starting new, that's likely not going to be for 2-3 years. In the meantime, I'm looking for a cheap and easy fix. Is there any kind of transparent sealer I can apply over the top of the existing vinyl to keep it watertight for the next few years?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless there are holes in the vinyl flooring it is probably getting through where the vinyl meets the tub or the wall. Just use a clear or white 100% silicone bath caulk to seal those junctions.

Make sure it is rated for resistance to mold/mildew.

Comment: Thanks. I plan on sealing up the seam around the tub, but I think most of the leaks are coming through the joints in the vinyl tile. Perhaps I'll just try to smooth a thin layer of silicone over the worst offenders.

Answer (score 0):

Along with Alaska's suggestion, a bath mat should solve your woes, and a little more splash discipline from shower users. Trying to make a bathtub out of one's bathroom floor always seemed a little silly to me.

Comment: I agree that a bathroom floor shouldn't need to be made into a bathtub, but bathroom floors should be able to sustain some occasional splashes or moisture without damaging the ceiling below. A few small but well placed splashes were all it took to get dripping into our dining room.